# The jQuery UI datepicker("option") function doesn't return the options

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Looking at the jQuery UI v1.9 API documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/datepicker/#method-option), it says:

> `option()`
>
> Returns: PlainObject
>
> Gets an object containing key/value pairs representing the current
>   datepicker options hash. This signature does not accept any arguments.

The documented code example is:

```
var options = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option" );
```

This doesn't work for me.  It should return a PlainObject, but it's returning a jQuery object holding a single item; the input element.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is the documentation wrong?  Have I found a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine found the answer to this.  I think the documentation is wrong.

To return the options you need to pass `'all'` as the second parameter:

```
var options = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "all" );
```

I eventually found a forum post about it too: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-option-method-does-not-retrieve-options-correctly